# Combine the .htaccess files for silverstripe and squeezr

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silverstripe

I am trying to combine two .htaccess files into one:

https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/3.1/.htaccess

AND

https://github.com/jkphl/squeezr/blob/master/.htaccess

I also want to exclude the CMS from any squeezr rules (i.e. links to http://www.mysite.co.nz/admin/.... should not run via squeezr.

Is it sufficient to basically combine the two .htaccess files and write the final redirection rule for silverstripe as follows:

`RewriteRule (?!^squeezr|admin)^.*$ framework/main.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Please let me know if you need more information in this question and I will add.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just combine the 2. There doesn't seem any conflict

https://gist.github.com/24b48c12d82c73e60a37

---

EDIT:

In your question you also mention that you want to exclude the cms from sqeezer, the idea makes sense, however, the `RewriteRule` you have posted does not at all, in fact I would be surprised if that did not throw an error.
The only thing the above rule would do (if it would work), would be to exclude squeezr files from being rewritten to framework, but that would never happen anyway, because the `RewriteCond`s before would already deny that (SilverStripe does not rewrite existing files).

so what you need to do is actually add a `RewriteCond` to the 2 squeezr rules, to tell them not to use `cms` and `framework`.

I believe adding the 2 following conditions (right before the squeezr rules) would do that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cms # exclude the silverstripe cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !framework # exclude the silverstripe framework which is by
```

(you can also view it as diff for the gist here: https://gist.github.com/Zauberfisch/d681474df67ced83ec1f/revisions)

---

the full config file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/error-404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /assets/error-500.html

<Files *.ss>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files web.config>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "\.ya?ml$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>



<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks

    # Start the rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

# REDIRECT ANY DIRECT IMAGE REQUEST TO A CACHED VERSION
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_BREAKPOINT} !\d+px
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([^&]*&)*squeezr=(0|false|no)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} squeezr.images=(\d+px) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cms # exclude the silverstripe cms
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !framework # exclude the silverstripe framework which is by the cms
    RewriteRule ^(.+)(\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))$ squeezr/cache/$1-%1$2 [NC,E=BREAKPOINT:%1,L]
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Please make sure that you set this path     ^^^     to the squeezr root directory that is also specified
# for the SQUEEZR_ROOT constant in the common engine configuration (SQUEEZR_ROOT/conf/common.php). If you
# apply the default setup for squeezr (i.e. put everything into a directory named "squeezr" under your
# website's document root), then you shouldn't have to change anything.
#############################################################################################################


# REDIRECT ANY DIRECT CSS REQUEST TO A CACHED VERSION
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_BREAKPOINT} !\d+px
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([^&]*&)*squeezr=(0|false|no)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} squeezr.css=(\d+x\d+@\d+(?:\.\d+)?) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !cms # exclude the silverstripe cms
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !framework # exclude the silverstripe framework which is by the cms
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ squeezr/cache/$1-%1.css [NC,E=BREAKPOINT:%1,L]
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# See above for hints on      ^^^     this path.
#############################################################################################################

### SILVERSTRIPE START ###
    RewriteRule ^vendor(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule silverstripe-cache(/|$) - [F,L,NC]
    RewriteRule composer\.(json|lock) - [F,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/framework/main.php$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . %1/install.php? [R,L]
### SILVERSTRIPE END ###
</IfModule>


#############################################################################################################
# Additional stuff for improving your website's delivery performance
#############################################################################################################
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css text/javascript text/json text/x-json text/x-json-stream application/x-javascript application/json application/x-json application/x-json-stream application/.*xml.* multipart/x-json-stream multipart/x-mixed-replace image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on

    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 35 days"

    # Text based files
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 35 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 35 days"

    # Default expiration
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: agreed, I just looked over the two config files, the both are limited to different criteria, so I don't see any point where they would be in conflict)